# Having a problem sorting flatlist by closest location in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create an app that shows schools close to your location. I am fetching a json and pulling in the addresses and the miles from the current location, but the flatlist is not sorting by least amount of miles.

I have tried following the steps listed in this thread [sorting the items in the flatList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249887/sorting-the-items-in-the-flatlist), but my flatlist is not sorted in distance order.

Here is how I am fetching the json:

```
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('json api')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: responseJson.schools,
          isLoading: false,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Here is my flatlist (lat1 and lon1 are from the json, and I am hard coding the latitude and longitude right now until I figure out how to insert my current location):

```
return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource.sort((a,b) => {
            const aDist = getDistance({
              latitude: +a.lat1,
              longitude: +a.lon1
            }, {
              latitude: 50,
              longitude: -50,
            })
            const bDist = getDistance({
              latitude: +b. lat1,
              longitude: +b.lon1
            }, {
              latitude: 50,
              longitude: -50
            })

            return aDist - bDist;
          })}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
```

The information is all showing correctly but not in the correct order. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a space in `latitude: +b. lat1`.

Comment: Can you post your getDistance function?

Comment: @fizzybear thanks I corrected that but it didn't change the expected behavior

Comment: @Mark i am using getDistance from geolib https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib so i just imported up to as import {getDistance} from 'geolib' -- would that not work?

Comment: @jas1533, that should be fine then. Can you try doing the sort before the return like this? `const sortedData = this.state.dataSource.sort((a,b) => { ...` And then put a console.log after the sort like this: `console.log(sortedData);` And finally `<FlatList data={sortedData} ...`

Comment: @Mark thanks, do you mean as follows? `const sortedData = this.state.dataSource.sort((a,b) => {...
          })`
          
      `console.log(sortedData);`

    `return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={sortedData}`     
          
I got the same result and the array was in the same unsorted order in the console

Comment: Are lat1 and lon1 the correct property names in your dataSource array of objects? Can you console.log some of your dataSource array and add it to your question above?

Comment: // this seems to work
const geolib = require('geolib');
const data = [
    {lat1: 80, lon1: -80},
    {lat1: 60, lon1: -60},
    {lat1: 70, lon1: -70},
    {lat1: 51, lon1: -51},
];
const sorted=data.sort((a,b) => {
    const aDist = geolib.getDistance({
      latitude: +a.lat1,
      longitude: +a.lon1
    }, {
      latitude: 50,
      longitude: -50,
    })
    const bDist = geolib.getDistance({
      latitude: +b. lat1,
      longitude: +b.lon1
    }, {
      latitude: 50,
      longitude: -50
    })
    return aDist - bDist;
  })
  console.log(sorted);

Comment: @Mark it was the property name - i had long1 in the array instead of lon1; thanks so much sorry i'm still new to this :)

Comment: Great to hear you solved it! And no need to apologise, we all make these little mistakes